# How to use "Use video" / "choose" button from video in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, video

I'm trying to upload my video chosen from library or recorded from camera to firebase. When I get the video from library there's a "choose" button on the image picker or when I record the video it says "Use video".
I think to run those buttons function you have to write the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function. But nothing happens when I record a video and click "choose" this is what I have as my code:

```
               if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {

            //if the camera is available, and if the rear camera is available, the let the image picker do this

            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
            imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 60
            imagePicker.videoQuality = .typeIFrame1280x720



            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            postAlert("Rear camera doesn't exist", message: "Application cannot access the camera.")
        }
    } else {
        postAlert("Camera inaccessable", message: "Application cannot access the camera.")
    }       
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {  
    print("didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo")
}
```

I want it to at least print to know that the video "choose button" is working. Any ideas on how to get the choose button to work? Any help would be kind. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adopting `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in the class header and setting `imagePicker.delegate` to `self` instead of doing this each time before you are presenting picker?